# Font awesome center horizontally

Tags: html, css

So for some reason I just can't seem to position my icons in the center of the div they are wrapped in. I have tried wrapping them in a div, calling them directly in css, many css combinations and parent classes it just wont budge. The only way I have got it to move is by adding "margin-left" which just isn't great in this responsive design situation.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <i class="icon-code"> </i>
    <p class="service-description">
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ribeye ham kielbasa, pork ball tip jowl pancetta kevin andouille capicola pastrami frankfurter short ribs tenderloin pork chop.
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.service-icons{
    margin-top:6%;
}
.service-icons i{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-color:#c1c1c1;
    color:#c1c1c1;
    font-size:72px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.icon-code i{
    text-align: center;
}
.service-icons i:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

For a live demo - [Click here](http://www.xronn.co.uk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`

Comment: I'm using this method currently now works perfectly thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` that should center it in the middle of the page/whatever container it is in.